# How to get map units to find current scale in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, proj

I need my OpenLayers application to be able to determine the current scale.  This is not for display (there is already the scale line for that).  This is because I have a scale-dependent style function, to display styles differently at different scales.  I need to be able to do it according to scales, not resolutions, because the styles and their respective scales, are configured by the user, and the user enters scale values similar to how they would in a GIS for layer display constraints.  (Ie, although scales are not great for on-screen, they are what users are used to using to constrain styles/layers to specific resolutions).

This is all working well in my app, changing styles as I zoom in and out.  Except that my calculation of the current scale is incorrect.  For testing purposes, I've simply calculating the scale (incorrectly) as:

`resolution * DPI`

I think that the correct way to calculate the scale would be:

`resolution * meters-per-map-unit * inches-per-metre * DPI`

The only part of this I cannot figure out is the metres-per-map-unit.  there is the `ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT` lookup, but I can't use it because I don't know what the current unit is.  My users may have swapped in any map of any projection in the application, so I need to be able to determine the current unit dynamically.

How can I get the current map unit from OpenLayers?

Or can I get it from proj4.js for the current projection? (and if so, is that the same thing?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **units** are within the **projection** of the view. From a map object, you can get it using:

```
var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
```

See also the API documentation of the [ol.proj.Projection#getUnits](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.Projection.html#getUnits) method.

Here's also an example **method to get the scale from a given resolution**:

```
var INCHES_PER_UNIT = {
  'm': 39.37,
  'dd': 4374754
};
var DOTS_PER_INCH = 72;

/**
 * @param {number} resolution Resolution.
 * @param {string} units Units
 * @param {boolean=} opt_round Whether to round the scale or not.
 * @return {number} Scale
 */
var getScaleFromResolution = function(resolution, units, opt_round) {
  var scale = INCHES_PER_UNIT[units] * DOTS_PER_INCH * resolution;
  if (opt_round) {
    scale = Math.round(scale);
  }
  return scale;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did actually search the documentation, but obviously not thoroughly enough.  I will post the solution I ended up using as a seperate answer, as it is a littrle different to yours.  But your answer was the basis of it, so I've accepted your answer.

Comment: Why DOTS_PER_INCH = 72 ?

Comment: Was inspired by the code back in OL2, see: https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/blob/release-2.13.1/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js#L1064-L1068

Comment: For anyone finding this several years later, and using Openlayers and Geoserver, note that Geoserver by default generates tiles at dpi of 90 not 72.  I started with 72 and noticed it was not correct and did more research to find this detail when using WMS: The OGC standard output resolution is 90 DPI.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @Alexandre's answer, I came up with something a little different that suits my use-case better.  In this case, I know that I have a map with a view and projection, and from that I can derive everything else required to calculate the scale except for the DPI.  In my app, DPI cannot be hard-coded because the app runs on mobile devices with screens of variable resolutions.  So DPI is the only parameter I pass in to my function.

This could all be done on one line, but I added the 3 `var` lines in order to make it more human readable.

This is what I've ended up using:

```
function mapScale (dpi) {
    var unit = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
    var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var inchesPerMetre = 39.37;

    return resolution * ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[unit] * inchesPerMetre * dpi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined 2 answers that already exist and this is the result.

```
import Units, { METERS_PER_UNIT } from 'ol/proj/Units';

const DOTS_PER_INCH = 72;
const INCHES_PER_METRE = 39.37;

function inchesPreUnit(unit: Units): number {
  return METERS_PER_UNIT[unit] * INCHES_PER_METRE;
}

function mapRatioScale({ map, toRound = true }): number {
    const resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    const unit = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();

    let scale = resolution * inchesPreUnit(unit) * DOTS_PER_INCH;
    return toRound ? Math.round(scale) : scale;
}

// usage
const scale = mapRatioScale({ map });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { getPointResolution } from "ol/proj";

const DEFAULT_DPI = 25.4 / 0.28;

function getScaleForResolution() {
  const resolution = getPointResolution(
    map?.getView().getProjection(),
    map?.getView().getResolution() ?? 0,
    map?.getView().getCenter() as Coordinate,
    "m"
  );
  const dpi = options.dpi || DEFAULT_DPI;
  const inchesPerMeter = 1000 / 25.4;
  return resolution * inchesPerMeter * dpi;
}

function onResolutionChange() {
  const resolutionScale = getScaleForResolution();

  const mapScale =
    resolutionScale < 1
      ? Math.round(1 / resolutionScale).toLocaleString() + " : 1"
      : "1 : " + Math.round(resolutionScale).toLocaleString();

  setCurrentScale(mapScale);
}
```

Comment: The questiom has already an accepted answer. Kindly explain how your solution can improve the results.