# OpenLayers, WMS MinScaleDenominator and MaxScaleDenominator

Tags: openlayers, wms, scale

In my OpenLayers map application I display many WMS layers from different sources. Some of them have display scale restrictions set by *MinScaleDenominator* and *MaxScaleDenominator* tags in WMS *GetCapabilities*.

What I want to achieve is to notify my application users to zoom in or zoom out to view particular layer.

How can I compare current map view zoom level to *MinScaleDenominator* and *MaxScaleDenominator* in OpenLayers?

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242424/how-to-get-map-units-to-find-current-scale-in-openlayers help?

Comment: helps, thank you! But I'm not sure how to get values of inchesPerMetre and DPI (used in mapScale function)?

Comment: inches per meter is 12(inches)*3.28084(ft in a metre) - DPI is usually 72 or 96 or so