# WMS - understanding <Min> and <MaxScaleDenominator>

Tags: openlayers, wms, scale, ogc

I am working on a personal web gis client and the first thing I am implementing is support for OGC WMS 1.3.0.

Right now, I am in the middle of greying out layers in my layer tree which are not visible at the current view scale.

From the official documentation I read:

> The  and  elements define the range of scales for which it is
>   appropriate to generate a map of a Layer. Because maps from a WMS may be viewed on arbitrary displays rather
>   than on paper, the values used are actually the scale denominators relative to a common display pixel size. (...) For the purposes of this International Standard, the common pixel size is defined to be 0,28 mm × 0,28 mm.
>   Because arbitrary clients can request maps from a server, the true pixel size of the final rendering device is
>   unknown to the server.

Probably is either that English is not my first language and that I am very bad with numbers, but I am struggling to figure out the meaning of this sentence.

Take [this WMS](https://servizigis.regione.emilia-romagna.it/wms/rete_escursionistica?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=Getcapabilities) for example. Some layers have `<MaxScaleDenominator>` equals to `94494.047619`.

First of all, how can I read this number in terms of scale? Does it represent the common `1:94494.047619` scale, or do I have to do some calculations with the standardize 0,28 mm × 0,28 mm pixel size to understand it?

Also, if

> the true pixel size of the final rendering device is unknown is there
>   a way to to the server

is there a way to retrieve it client side (if that is indeed required for what I need to do)?

**EDIT1**

So I already got pretty good results. I have the below code which logs to console the current scale of my view (might be not 100% clean, but it seems to work, I adapted it from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242424/how-to-get-map-units-to-find-current-scale-in-openlayers)):

```
import {METERS_PER_UNIT} from 'ol/proj/Units.js';

// return current scale in map units according to DPI
function mapScale(map, dpi) {
    var unit = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
    var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var inchesPerMetre = 39.37;
    return resolution * METERS_PER_UNIT[unit] * inchesPerMetre * dpi;
}

export function getScale(map) {
    map.getView().on('propertychange', function(e) {
        switch (e.key) {
            case 'resolution':
                // log DPI to console
                console.log("DPI:" + window.devicePixelRatio);
                // log scale in map units to console
                console.log("1:" + mapScale(map, window.devicePixelRatio * 96));
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Now I can see in the console when I am farther than the aforementioned `<MaxScaledenominator>` (94494.047619), and indeed, if I turn on the layer it won't show up till I have reach at least this value (actually it turns on at 1:72223 at minimum as I am using OpenStreetMap basemaps and this is one of its fixed scale level).

This seems to confirm that the numbers are meant like "traditional" scales (*i.e.* 1:94494.047619). Can anybody please confirm and elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: A good definition with examples can be read here: http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1188 at pages 25+

Comment: @Revo that indeed is a good reference! Will update my question or will hopefully asnwer my own question if I can solve myself after reading and testing. Thanks!